# Минимизация точек на контуре с#

Tags: c#, emgucv

Пишу программу на с# которая по фотографии находит контур предмета и создает чертеж контура в формате dxf.
Все сделал вроде но есть одно но у меня каждый пиксель это точка, а проектор или плоттер такое обработать не сможет.

Нужно теперь убрать все лишние точки, то есть на прямых оставить только 2 точки, начало и конец.(прямые могут быть под разным углом).
На кривых убрать равно столько сколько можно и не потерять качество контура.

Смотрел разные алгоритмы но результат пока не нашел, сейчас начал копать в сторону Egmu cv.

Снизу пример фотографии оригинала и результат работы.
[image: Оригинал]
[image: Найденный контур]

Может кто то хоть что то знает, нужна любая помощь. Спасибо!

Comment: залил, мне подсказали что в OpenCV (оно же emguCV) есть функция ApproxPoly которая может помочь, сейчас буду проверять

Comment: Спасибо! Если получится разобраться, обязательно пишите! Уверен, многим будет интересен ответ!

Comment: Можно попробовать метод [GraphicsPath.Flatten](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fz2042a8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Спасибо за совет, описание функции мне понравилось сейчас посмотрим как на практике,как сделаю сразу и отпишусь!

Comment: Сделал но не могу посчитать на сколько меньше точек стало...

float accuracy=7f;
myPath.Flatten(translateMatrix, accuracy);


если сравнить так points.Count с myPath.PointCount то значения одинаковые , как будто количество точек не уменьшилось.
Но по факту явно стало меньше. 
Как взять массив point'ов из  myPath.Flatten(translateMatrix, accuracy)???

Comment: Разобрался , и понял почему количество одинаковое
надо просто удалить повторы.
Например:

"339 397
340 398
340 399
341 400" оригинал.
"397 339
397 340
398 340
399 341 
400 342
401 342" -после обработки
сейчас удалю повторы и отпишусь о том на сколько хорошо выходит

Comment: Сделал, точек становиться меньше ,но это не то, много не правильно выходит , на пример линии он очень плохо обрабатывает записывает те же координаты .есть еще какие то советы ?